# Align 90deg rotated div with parents edge/border-box

Tags: html, css, transform, rotatetransform

Is there away to achieve this or is it just a limitation of CSS at the moment and the unconventional layout I'm trying to create?

As you can see in the example, it's almost there but the edge of the rotated text overlaps into the parent containers padding.

The width of the rotated div will change, so I can't set a pixel value to offset it. The only other solution I can think of is to use `position: absolute`, which isn't ideal for what I'm going to do next with the layout ...but that might be the only option?

```css
/* Body */
body {
  background: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* Header */
.page-head {
  border-right: 2px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: end;
  height: 100vh;
  height: -webkit-fill-available;
  height: -moz-available;
  height: stretch;
  padding: 24px 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: height 0.12s ease-out, top 0.12s ease-out, width 0.12s ease-out;
  width: 48px;
}

/* Logo */
.site-logo {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.24);
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 32px;
  stroke: black;
  width: 32px;
}

/* Toggle */
.contrast {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.24);
  display: flex;
  justify-self: end;
  align-self: normal;
  margin: auto 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: center;
}

/* Data & Time */
.os-menu {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.24);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-self: end;
  align-self: normal;
  padding: 0;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-head" role="banner">

  <a class=" site-logo" href="index.html">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 64 64" height="32" width="32">
      <defs>
        <clipPath id="a">
          <circle cx="32" cy="32" r="31" fill="none" />
        </clipPath>
      </defs>
      <circle cx="32" cy="32" r="31" fill="none" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" />
      <g clip-path="url(#a)" fill="none" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2">
        <path d="M16.19 58.57V5.43L31.94 32 47.69 5.43v53.14M31.94 32v31.49" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" />
      </g>
    </svg>
  </a>

<!--   <div class="os-menu">
    <div id="date" class="os-menu__item">Date</div>
    <div id="time" class="os-menu__item">Time</div>
  </div> -->

  <p class="contrast"><a href="#" class="contrast__link"><span class="contrast__label">Mode</span><span class="contrast__switch"></span></a></p>

</div>
```

Comment: writing-mode is probably what you need : see if  `.contrast {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.24);
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  writing-mode:vertical-rl
}` is morelike what you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

I've updated the `transform` and `transform-origin` values in `.contrast` class. and in the `.page-header` class I've changes `justify-item: end` to `justify-content: space-beetween`

```css
/* Body */

body {
  background: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* Header */

.page-head {
  border-right: 2px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100vh;
  height: -webkit-fill-available;
  height: -moz-available;
  height: stretch;
  padding: 24px 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: height 0.12s ease-out, top 0.12s ease-out, width 0.12s ease-out;
  width: 48px;
}


/* Logo */

.site-logo {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.24);
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 32px;
  stroke: black;
  width: 32px;
}


/* Toggle */

.contrast {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.24);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(0, -50%);
  transform-origin: top center;
}


/* Data & Time */

.os-menu {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.24);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-self: end;
  align-self: normal;
  padding: 0;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-head" role="banner">

  <a class=" site-logo" href="index.html">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 64 64" height="32" width="32">
      <defs>
        <clipPath id="a">
          <circle cx="32" cy="32" r="31" fill="none" />
        </clipPath>
      </defs>
      <circle cx="32" cy="32" r="31" fill="none" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" />
      <g clip-path="url(#a)" fill="none" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="2">
        <path d="M16.19 58.57V5.43L31.94 32 47.69 5.43v53.14M31.94 32v31.49" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" />
      </g>
    </svg>
  </a>

  <!--   <div class="os-menu">
    <div id="date" class="os-menu__item">Date</div>
    <div id="time" class="os-menu__item">Time</div>
  </div> -->

  <p class="contrast"><a href="#" class="contrast__link"><span class="contrast__label">Mode</span><span class="contrast__switch"></span></a></p>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks good! Out of interest, if I had a 3rd item in the header I guess with this CSS it would be centred? If I wanted that positioned to the bottom (stacked) as well, how would that work with `space-beetween`? Or would you just wrap both elements in a div and apply the same CSS to that? I thought `margin-top: auto` would work but that overlapped both divs.

Comment: wrapping both elements in div will work just fine.